# Disable button in kotlin programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning kotlin with previous experience in SwiftUI. Is there any way to disable button with modifier, depending on the state variable in Kotlin?
I want to disable the button, for example if some boolean variable is true

```
Button(onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.size(width = 200.dp, height = 50.dp),
            ),
            content = {
                Text(text = "Continue")
            })
```

Like this in SwiftUI:

```
Button("Continue") {
        
    }
    .disabled(false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this parameter on the button composable

```
Button(enabled = false, onClick = {}) {
            Text("Example")
        }
```